# Online version of book called "Aiding Talmud Study"?

Tags: talmud-gemara, jewish-books, books-generally

Does anyone know whether an online version (PDF, ebook etc.) of a book called "Aiding Talmud Study" by Aryeh Carmell exists?

Comment: The only version of סייעתא לגמרא I found online was: https://books.google.nl/books?id=Rq-kVjTnlP0C&printsec=copyright&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false  however, not all pages are included.

Answer (score 1):

check out... https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chaim.talmudquest
"The terms are taken from The Students Guide to Talmud with the permission of its author of blessed memory, Rabbi Aryeh Carmel z"l and Feldheim Publishers."